# Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Preview does not Install Phone SDK 8 in VM

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, vmware-player

I download the Windows 8.1 / IE 11 VM from modern.ie, start it in VMPlayer and want to install the Visual Studio 2013 Preview. The installer does not offer to optionally also install the Windows Phone SDK 8.
I thought the reason might be the Phone Emulators need Hyper-V.
I changed the VM Operating system type from Windows 8 to Hyper-v and checked the Box "Virtualize Intel ..." in the Processor Settings.
When I call `systeminfo` on the command line in the Virtual Windows 8.1 it reads:

```
VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
Virtualizaion Enabled in Firmware: Yes
Second Level Address Translation: Yes
Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

Is it possible to run the Phone SDK in a virtual Windows 8.1?

I have no idea what the installer is checking before offering (or not) to install the Phone SDK. That Virtualization might be the issue is only a guess.

Comment: Have you check your BIOS not just through the systeminfo that the HyperV is enabled?

Comment: This is similar though it's Windows Phone 7. I also recently encountered that one but got it fixed through HyperV http://www.luisleo.net/error-with-windows-phone-7-emulator-solved/

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. You can install the SDK separately if you don't install the emulator, but you cannot run the emulator because you're already in a Hyper-V VM, Inception VMs are not allowed. Hopefully MS will let you connect from VS to a sibling VM someday.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, the problem was not the virtualization.
The VM I started to work with was a 32 bit Installation of Windows 8.1 Preview. Since the Stand alone Phone SDK could only be installed on an 64 bit system, I setup an own VM with the Windows 8.1 64 bit preview and tried again. When I installed the VS 2013 ultimate preview it was possible to check the Phone SDK.
Hyper-V was activated when the VS installation finished.
The VM's operating system is set to Windows 8 64 bit